Comedy with exaggeration, made up stories in TV shows
Salam! This is kind of a funny question but since it's so common atleast in the subcontinent TV scene, so I'm asking this, as people tend not to care about this, rather sometimes they claim to do something very noble as they help people have some good time, away from daily life worries and tensions.
Do comedy shows where the comedians overly exaggerate, tell made up stories, mock each other (they are okay with it, its all scripted) come under "lying to make someone laugh"? Everyone knows that what these people are saying is not true, but all this done in the name of comedy.
Some examples:

A comedian in a getup of some historical figure and his fellows mocking him, for example making fun of Mustasim Billah for being naive, materialistic and surrendering to Hulego Khan.

Fellow comedians making fun of their colleague, who is fat, and they overly exaggerate stuff, like "he first ate the food, then the utensils and then the cook" etc.


